# How to find value of auto bin in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I want to know the value of the auto bin when I plot histograms in pandas.

```
db['Vt'].hist(bins='auto',color = "blue")
```

I don't know how to find the value of bins in this situation.
Thanks for you answers!

Answer (score 1):

`bins='auto'` : specifies automatically-determined bins directly in matplotlib. This uses the maximum of the [`Sturges`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Number_of_bins_and_width) and [`Freedman-Diaconis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule) bin choice.

This works with `matplotlib version` >= 2.0 and `numpy version` >= 1.11

Check [`numpy.hist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) docs.